# addToBackStack() didn't work. Back to home not previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm pretty new to android. When I try to use `addToBackStack()`, I encountered a problem.

When I press back button in fragment 2, it didn't go to fragment 1 but to home.

Why? Is there anything wrong in my code?
Thanks!

MaiinActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.id_frame, new firstFrag(), "firstFrag");
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfragtest2.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/id_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        ></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

firstFrag.java

```
public class firstFrag extends Fragment {


    private Button button1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

        button1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction myFTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                myFTransaction.replace(R.id.id_frame, new secondFrag());
                myFTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                myFTransaction.commit();



            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

first_frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is frag 1!!"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="move to frag 2"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also try with remove this line  `myFTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this snippet in your Main Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

And log the count of your fragments.

Comment: sorry addToBackStack() is required when your calling your fragment.So when you are creating your fragments the backStack count increases.Hence it is important that you have to add AddToBackStack();

Comment: When I use `getFragmentManager()` this method isn't necessary in the root activity, but if I'm nesting fragments and using `getChildFragmentManager` I must use this.... wonder why

Comment: @ElliotM If your using the v4 support library then if you'll see in the super class method `onBackPressed()` it automatically pops the back stack, if you're not then you need to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `null` use tag name in `addToBackStack()` , in both fragments `oncall`.
I used the following code, it's working for me:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.mainfragment, new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
ft.addToBackStack("Fragment1");             
ft.commit();
```

Comment: No luck for me.:( You mean you can back to previous fragment in this way?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you should use addToBackStack(String name) method before you commit. But the real issue is that your MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity. Looks like it overrides the Back Button behavior. Try extend Activity. Should work fine. In this case you have to deal with possible Action Bar misbehavior though.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_main, new ListFragment())
            .commit();
}

public void startDetailFragment (View view) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_main, new DetailFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```